# What happens to data persisted with RMS if I shutdown the device

Tags: java-me, rms

I need to save some data in my j2me application using RMS, but I'm not sure about what happens to this data if I shutdown the phone or if the it runs of out battery. Next time I start the phone, will the data be still there??

Just one more question, do you know where the data persisted with RMS goes(phone memory or a memory card)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might answer your question:

A class representing a record store. A record store consists of a collection of records which will remain persistent across multiple invocations of the MIDlet. **The platform is responsible for making its best effort to maintain the integrity of the MIDlet's record stores throughout the normal use of the platform, including reboots, battery changes, etc**.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/RecordStore.html).

Answer (score 2):

Data stored in RMS is persistent. In other words, it stays there even after removing the battery, just like the installed apps stay there.

RMS data is stored in phone memory.

Comment: Thanks mr_lou. I asked because at the moment,I'm just running tests on the emulator and yesterday after a power failure all the data I had saved using RMS was gone when I run the emulator again. That was why I thought RMS would only keep the data while the device is on.

Comment: sorry to bother you, but do you  know if what is says here is true? http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/185851-can-i-store-RMS-on-memory-card If I install a midlet in a memory card, I could have more space than if I install the same midlet in the phone's memory?

Comment: It's the same deal for Android phones and JavaME enabled phones: Naturally, if you install (or move the MIDlet after install) from the Phone Memory to the SD card, then obviously you'll have more Phone Memory available.
I believe that RMS is stored the same place you store the MIDlet. So if it's installed on SD card, I believe RMS data is also stored on SD card. But there's also a chance it's device dependent.

Comment: @eddy, I've confirmed on Nokia that if the app is installed in SD card then the RMS data will also be saved there as well therefore giving you almost as much storage space as is available on the card. That said, j2me devices are Limited Devices and their design principle means that you should be ultra-conservative as well. So don't get surprised if something breaks with large datasets.